# Can I upload binary packages to a Launchpad PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

Well, I have a launchpad account and a just set up a PPA.

Since I don't have generated source packages, I'd like to upload my binary packages to the PPA.

Though it seems not possible... Is there a way to avoid create source packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** You can only upload source packages to a PPA, for security and licensing (open-source) reasons; Launchpad will then build it into binary packages for you.

Comment: I don't know how to make a source package... Using `debhelper` I'm getting binary packages only

Comment: Then how did [WebUpd8 ship Oracle Java](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a GPG key? Does Launchpad know your key? In term of packaging, you can use `debuild -S -sa -k<YourGPGkey>` to build your `*.desc` file. After this, you can upload your source-package, `*.dsc` file to PPA. Launchpad will compile your code.