# Personal Package Archives (PPA) questions

Tags: ppa, open-source

I am new to PPA and have a question about it. If I want to upload self-write software in PPA, do I need to open source? I mean to give the .cpp files. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A lot of ppas have closed source stuff in them (Nvidia proprietary drivers come to mind), so unless you are using open source componenets that require your work to be open source (a la wikimedia Commons) you should be ok.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/234005/is-there-a-repository-ppa-that-collects-closed-source-non-free-software

Comment: @brndn2k, but PPA need you to upload source code and build in Launchpad

Comment: @crazymumu You are most welcome, but I don't think I did very much :)